# New to Javascript, having logic issues with menu interactions

Tags: javascript, menu

Here's my jsfiddle for easier referencing:

http://jsfiddle.net/Syrne/gAgZr/1/

---

And here's the raw JS code:

```
var main = document.getElementById("main");
var clicked = false;

var dropdown1 = document.getElementById("box1");
var dropdown2 = document.getElementById("box2");

var icon1 = document.getElementById("icon1");
var icon2 = document.getElementById("icon2");
var icon3 = document.getElementById("icon3");
var icon4 = document.getElementById("icon4");

var select1 = document.getElementById("box1select");
var select2 = document.getElementById("box2select");

var originalHeight1 = dropdown1.style.height;
var originalHeight2 = dropdown2.style.height;

var originalSelect1 = select1.style.height;
var originalSelect2 = select2.style.height;

var selectImage = document.getElementsByClassName("select_image");

function clearAll() {
    for (var i = 0; i < selectImage.length; i++) {
        selectImage[i].style.display = "none";
    }
}

function fadeAll() {
    for (var i = 0; i < selectImage.length; i++) {
        selectImage[i].style.opacity = "0";
        selectImage[i].style.transition = "opacity 0.4s";
    }
}

icon1.onclick = function () {
    if (clicked === true) {
        dropdown1.style.height = originalHeight1;
        select1.style.height = originalSelect1;
        fadeAll();
        clicked = false;
    } else {
        clicked = true;
        clearAll();
        dropdown1.style.height = "320px";
        dropdown1.style.transition = "height 0.5s";
        select1.style.height = "65%";
        select1.style.transition = "height 0.48s";
    }
};

icon2.onclick = function () {
    if (clicked === true) {
        dropdown1.style.height = originalHeight1;
        select1.style.height = originalSelect1;
        fadeAll();
        clicked = false;
    } else {
        clicked = true;
        clearAll();
        dropdown1.style.height = "320px";
        dropdown1.style.transition = "height 0.5s";
        select1.style.height = "65%";
        select1.style.transition = "height 0.48s";
    }

};

icon3.onclick = function () {
    if (clicked === true) {
        dropdown1.style.height = originalHeight1;
        select1.style.height = originalSelect1;
        fadeAll();
        clicked = false;
    } else {
        clicked = true;
        clearAll();
        dropdown1.style.height = "320px";
        dropdown1.style.transition = "height 0.5s";
        select1.style.height = "65%";
        select1.style.transition = "height 0.48s";
    }

};

icon4.onclick = function () {
    if (clicked === true) {
        dropdown1.style.height = originalHeight1;
        select1.style.height = originalSelect1;
        fadeAll();
        clicked = false;
    } else {
        clicked = true;
        clearAll();
        dropdown1.style.height = "320px";
        dropdown1.style.transition = "height 0.5s";
        select1.style.height = "65%";
        select1.style.transition = "height 0.48s";
    }

};
```

---

So I'm quite new to JS and I think this may just be a problem logic-wise, but here's the scenario that I WANT to happen:

User clicks one of the four buttons, it drops down an information window. While that window is still open, user clicks a different button. The window contracts and re-expands with info for the button they clicked.

As of right now, if a user clicks ANY button while the window is expanded, it will simply contract the window and nothing more. I tried calling the "onclick" function again within each function, but it would execute at the same time as the menu and cancel any animations.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You could use a boolean variable called menuItemClicked that will be true if a least one menu button is clicked. And after when you have your if statements you can factor that in and also create another option when a button is clicked but the menuItemClicked is also true to first contract all the expanded menus and then expand the one clicked.

Comment: Thank you! I'll give this a try as soon as possible.

Comment: Hello, I've added the boolean values that you suggested and I seem to be getting closer, but I'm not quite there yet. Here's a revised fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Syrne/gAgZr/6/

As you can see, now once a button is clicked, another cannot be clicked unless the original is un-clicked. This is close to what I want, except I want Javascript to automatically un-click the original button when an alternate one is clicked.

Thank you for the support, please bear with me as I am very new to Javascript!